# I want to get employee's department data from the req department id passed to the url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do I use optional query filter on these route like "/employees?department=4" and returning data where department number is 4

```
app.get("/employees", (req, res) => {
    dataService.getAllEmployees().then(function(data) {
        res.json(data);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        var error = { "message": err };
        res.json(error);
    });
```

I already have function in dataService module that return a promise of department with id below

```
function getEmployeesByDepartment(department) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            employees.forEach((element) => {
                if (element.department == department) {
                    resolve(element);
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            reject("no data returned");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the query parameters using the [`req.query`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) object.

In your case the code will be something like:

```
if (req.query.department) {
  return getEmployeesByDepartment(req.query.department).then(
    data => res.json(data)
  );
} else {
  return dataService.getAllEmployees().then(
    data => res.json(data)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `req.query` to fetch query string data and pass department to `getEmployeesByDepartment` function.

```
app.get("/employees", (req, res) => {
  var department  = req.query.department || "";
  if(department){
    getEmployeesByDepartment(department).then(data => res.json(data));
  }
  else{
    dataService.getAllEmployees().then((data) => {
      res.json(data);
  }).catch((err) => {
      var error = { "message": err };
      res.json(error);
  }
);
```